# Check if there is a location_id and manager_id with the same name (they are from different tables)

Tags: sql, plsql

So on that code I checked the uniqueness of `department_id` and `department_name`. Now I would like to do the same with `manager_id` and `locations_id`. Please keep in mind that `manager_id` is from table `EMPLOYEES` and `locations_id` is from table `LOCATIONS`.

I wonder if I can just continue that statement:

```
upper(s.department_id) = upper(d.department_id)
OR upper(s.department_name) = upper(d.department_name)
```

But I think that will not be enough, because it will check only in the DEPARTMENTS table. Not from LOCATIONS and EMPLOYEES like I want. Please advise.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_dep(p_id   NUMBER,
                                    p_name VARCHAR2,
                                    p_mgr  NUMBER,
                                    p_loc  NUMBER) IS
  BEGIN

    MERGE INTO departments d
    USING (
            SELECT
              p_id   department_id,
              p_name department_name,
              p_mgr  manager_id,
              p_loc  location_id
            FROM dual) s
    ON (   upper(s.department_id) = upper(d.department_id)
           OR upper(s.department_name) = upper(d.department_name))
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES (s.department_id, s.department_name, s.manager_id, s.location_id);

    IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
      INSERT INTO error_depa VALUES (p_id, p_name, p_mgr, p_loc);
    END IF;

  END;
```

**EDIT - additional information**
I got an error that there are not enough values for LOCATIONS and EMPLOYEES table. But I also tried to make this with exception and no_data_found. Can you modify this code and help me with that please? I would like to check the same for locations_id and manager_id.

```
create or replace procedure add_de(
                  p_id NUMBER,
                  p_name VARCHAR2,
                  p_mgr NUMBER,
                  p_loc NUMBER
                )
is
    v_dummy number;
begin
    select  1
      into  v_dummy
      from  departments
      where department_name = p_name OR DEPARTMENT_ID = p_id ;
    insert
      into error_depa
      values(
            p_id,
             p_name,
             p_mgr,
             p_loc
            );
  exception
    when no_data_found
      then
        insert
          into departments
          values(
                 p_id,
                 upper(p_name),
                 p_mgr,
                 p_loc
                );
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_dep(p_id   NUMBER,
                                p_name VARCHAR2,
                                p_mgr  NUMBER,
                                p_loc  NUMBER) IS
BEGIN

MERGE INTO departments d
USING (
        SELECT
          p_id   department_id,
          p_name department_name,
          p_mgr  manager_id,
          p_loc  location_id
        FROM dual) s
ON (   upper(s.department_id) = upper(d.department_id)
       OR upper(s.department_name) = upper(d.department_name))
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
***INSERT(department_id, department_name,manager_id,location_id)*** VALUES (s.department_id, s.department_name, s.manager_id, s.location_id);

COMMIT;

MERGE INTO employees trg
USING (
        SELECT
          * 
        FROM employees
        where
        manager_id = p_mgr) src
ON (   upper(trg.manager_id) = upper(src.manager_id))
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
***INSERT(department_id, ...)*** VALUES (src.department_id, ....);

COMMIT;

MERGE INTO locations trg
USING (
        SELECT
          * 
        FROM locations
        where
        locations_id = p_loc) src
ON (   upper(trg.locations_id) = upper(src.locations_id))
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
***INSERT(locations_id, ...)*** VALUES (src.locations_id, ....);

COMMIT;

IF SQL%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
  INSERT INTO error_depa VALUES (p_id, p_name, p_mgr, p_loc);
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: I got an error that there are not enough values for LOCATIONS and EMPLOYEES table. But I also tried to make this with exception and no_data_found. Can you modify this code and help me with that please. I would like to check the same for locations_id and manager_id.

Comment: The error with "no enoght values" is cause by your insert.You didn't provide the number of values that is need in order to complete all your target columns. Please re-write like this " Merge into "YOUR TABLE" trg using ( .... ) on (..) when not matched then insert (YOUR TARGET COLUMNS) values (YOUR VALUES FROM THE ABOVE SELECT);